# Laravel API Routes manipulate the default JSON return

Tags: json, laravel, laravel-5

Let's say I have 2 tables. `users` & `books`.
The tables look like this
users:

```
id, name
1, Jone
2, Doe
```

books:

```
id, name, user_id
3, Dummy book1, 1
4, Dummy book2, 1
5, Dummy book3, 2
```

When I try to return all the books belong to a user (ex. user 1) like this

```
$query->where('id', 1)->join('books', 'users.id', '=', 'books.user_id');
```

I get JSON, BUT the issue is JSON display `id` for books not the user like this:

```
id: 3,//this is the book id not the user id
user_id: 1
...
...
id: 4,
user_id: 1
```

How I can make my query display the id as the user id like this

```
id:1
... whatever
```

Better yet, how I can manipulate the whole JSON so I can rename the keys? For example `books.name` to `books_name` and `users.name` to `user_name`
I don't like the default JSON return

One of the reason I ask this that's if you join 2 tables or more the `id` will always be the last `table.id`

Comment: Can you post the whole query? If you don't explicitly say which attributes to select, SQL has no way of knowing if you want `users.id` or `books.id` since you're joining the tables.

Comment: You can use `->select(DB::raw("users.id AS user_id",),  ...other rows you want to get back from the DB)`

Comment: @Derek this is much cleaner answer and it put me in control of what return from the query. Put it as answer so I can select it as the correct answer.

Comment: I'm glad I could help, @Yamona!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to achieve what you want is to define the parameters in laravels built `select`:

```
$query->select(DB::raw("users.id AS user_id",), ...other rows you want to get back from the DB)
```

Just make sure to define the parameters you need in the select.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using relationships the true Laravel way. So in your books model you would have a relation to the user. Then you can use the `with('user')` method on your query for eager loading the user! Way easier and cleaner!

```
Book::find($id)->with('user');
```

Using the `find` method is much better when working with IDs.

Then in your Book model:

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}
```

I do not actually know the relationship between the book and user so I am just guessing.

Another tip: if you are doing this in a controller, use [Route Model Binding](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/routing#route-model-binding) so that you don't have to even look up the book by its ID.